# How do i connect to a spare test PC running linux?

Tags: ssh, web-server

I have been using shared hosting for a few years now and i feel the need to switch to a dedicated server because one of the websites i run needs more & more resources (and i'm interested in server side stuff and i would like to learn more)

I'm no unix wizard. I'm ok with basic unix commands (ssh, remote editing files using vi .. ) so instead of paying for a server during the first few months, I installed centos and the basic lamp stack on a spare pc to practice a little and get my hands dirty before the big switch.

My question is : How do i connect to the pc running centos from another computer, through ssh) ?
(either both computers are connected on the same network (wifi) or each computer is connected on a distinct network) ?

ps : I went with centos for no particular reason. Would you advise me to change for Ubuntu, debian or something else ?
And any ideas/advices for a server admin newbie are welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend this proven method (taken from Home Networking for Dummies):

[image: Now just plug it in there!]

1. Position the cable as shown in the picture
2. Tilt it slightly
3. Plug it in

Comment: That's not going to work. For the machine to be connected to the network via Ethernet, the cable must be connected. Your picture shows a disconnected cable. :)

Comment: My mistake, updated :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's fine to run CentOS, as that's most likely what your dedicated server or VPS will use anyway.

To enable ssh access from the CentOS box, ensure that either

1. You select a server installation type during installation, or
2. You specifically install the openssh-server package during or after installation.

In most installations, openssh-server should be installed by default.

Windows doesn't include any ssh clients. To connect to the machine using ssh, try a program such as [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/).

On the Mac, you can just use ssh from Terminal, just as you would from any other Unix box.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer.
My question wasn't clear enough.

I will be trying to connect to the test machine through Terminal (ssh) from an iMac.
So what i should have asked is how do i configure the test machine to make it 'reachable/visible' on the network.

Comment: I've expanded my answer based on your clarification. Enjoy!

Comment: Yes thanks.

So let's say openssh-server is running on the test machine. How can i connect to it ?
In order to connect to a server using ssh, i need a username/hostname/port/password. I guess i need to manually configure all that on the test machine, right ? (How ?)

And thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Have you finished the CentOS installation yet? If not, you really should do that first.

Comment: Yes, i installed Centos but i'm not sure I selected a server profile during the installation. I'm now trying to install and setup php&mysql . Maybe i should startover.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with CentOS, but I can highly recommend Ubuntu Server (Not the Desktop) version. The Desktop version comes with a huge load of stuff that you will never need on a web server - and omits a lot of the things that are required. The community support is also excellent.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I considered Ubuntu but chose to try centos because i'm not very familiar with the different linux distributions and their nuances so i thought that since Ubuntu has this 'mainstream' image, maybe even its server version is cluttered with the stuff you are talking about that isn't needed.

My problem is that i'm curious and really interested in this stuff but my priority is to learn fast and be operationnal asap. That's why I decided to pick a distribution (pretty much randomly) and stick with it instead of wasting time playing around with each one :)